# how to create cassandra keyspace in docker container?

Tags: cassandra, docker-compose

How to create key-space in Cassandra using Docker compose file. I have mentioned my commands in .cql file inside my docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder and trying to give command on docker compose as follows:

```
command: /bin/bash -c "exec cqlsh -f /cmpi/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.cql"
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To create a keyspace while bringing the docker container up and running, follow the following steps:

1. Create a dummy cassandra service which depends upon main cassandra service
2. Create a wait-for-it script which waits for cassandra at 9042 port.
3. Then inside a shell script write cqlsh -f command to take schema.cql(which contains commands to create keyspace and tables)